# How to rollover the logcat files in android?

Tags: android, logging

I have got to put a log of logs in my Android application so the logfile keeps growing. At some time, it will be difficult to go through the complete log file.

Coming to the point. I need to get rollover of log concept in Android just like we do in Java. I see there is an option in Android. The following is the command but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
"logcat -v time -f " + path + "LogCatFileName.txt -r 1000 -n 3 "
```

This command creates 5 logcat files irrespective of `-n` option and creates 16 kB size of every file irrespective of `-r` option. Looks like default value of these variables are not changing. Can someone help me resolve this?